# How can I access the XML file under SharePoint Mapped Folder for Creating Xml Reader?

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, xmlreader

[image: SharePoint Mapped Folder Structure]

I used this code to access the Specific XML under the SharePoint Mapped Folder;

`XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
string.Format("{0}\\{1}", SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\ADMIN\\AIP_RefinementPanel"), "CustomFilterCategoryDefinition.xml")));`

But I got an error during the deployment. This code doesn't work to access this XML file. How can I fix my fault?

Thank you,

MKacar

Comment: What is your actual name of the resource? It is unclear why you are trying to provide path to physical file as a argument...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work if you omit the call to *GetManifestResourceStream*. I suppose you want to read a file from the filesystem not a resource embedded to your assembly.

```
string templatePath = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE");
string xmlPath = Path.Combine(templatePath, @"ADMIN\AIP_RefinementPanel\CustomFilterCategoryDefinition.xml");
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the Url for you Xml file (and you know it because it's your custom Wsp and Xml file is deployed to some mapped virtual folder) it's better to get local file system path to file and feed it to XmlReader, as it may fail with Url due to authorization needed.

For instance I have a project with some Xml and Xslt files deployed to 'layouts' mapped folder

[image]

And I got access to Config.xml in next way

```
var configDirPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/_layouts/LMUI/Configuration");
var configFilePath = configDirPath + "\\" + "Config.xml";
```

Read MSDN documentation on HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx to get more info.

Comment: This will work only for files accessible via URLs mapped by the SP module and only if your code is running in the HTTP context. You can ensure the former by a clever deployment of you files but as for the latter it may not be possible - you can have your code in a workflow, PS cmdlet etc. The *SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath* will give you the local path in all scenarios.

   --- Ferda